# Adding Data in XmlObject

Tags: java, xml, web-services, cdata, xmlbeans

I have to code a Web service client, compliant to `Axis2 1.5.4`. The part of code giving the problem is as follows:

```
String my_var = "some value";
MetaDataEntry metaDataEntry = MetaDataEntry.Factory.newInstance();
metaDataEntry.setKey(MetaDataKey.Enum.forInt(key));
metaDataEntry.setValue(my_var);
```

Now basically the `setKey` woks fine but `setValue` expects an `XmlObject` value while according to the sample response document I have got, the `xml` structure should be like :

```
....
    <MetaDataEntry>
        <key>some_key_enum</key>
        <value>some _value</value>
    </MetaDataEntry>
....
```

I've tried using :

```
MetaDataEntry.setValue(XmlObject.Factory.parse("<value>"+my_var+"</value>"));
```

but it formats the value tag as `<value><value>some_value</value></value>`. I've also tried :

```
metaDataEntry.setValue(XmlObject.Factory.parse(my_var));
```

but it gives the exception: *Unexpected Element: CDATA*. Can anybody please help me write the correct statement?

Comment: What does your XSD look like?

Comment: The only element having problem is value element. The value element is declared as xs:anytype. Now, when client code is generated through wsdl2java, an interface is created for MetaDataEntry element and inside that I have setValue method and that accepts XmlObject type of value. I am basically facing problem in how can i pass a simple text value in setValue method such that there is no nesting of value tag.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using an XmlString value:

```
metaDataEntry.setValue(XmlString.Factory.newValue(my_var));
```